# Can this hardware failure be a faulty motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I have a self built PC which is running for around seven years now without a problem. Yesterday, in the middle of streaming Netflix on Ubuntu, the screen froze. Only a hard reset worked. After the reset, the PC went on and off a couple of times, one time I briefly saw that it booted into BIOS. Then it booted back into the OS, but network was down. I turned it off and tried again. Now I see the "power on" light for ~2 seconds, then it goes off again. The fans all briefly turn on and then off again. Then there is a pause of ~10 seconds until which the cycle starts again. It does not boot into BIOS or the OS anymore. My screen also briefly goes on without showing anything, so there seems to be a signal, which then disappears again.

Can this be due to a faulty motherboard? I visually inspected the board, but could not see any burned capacitors or any other signs of damage. Is there any way to determine, where the problem is? Unfortunately I do not know how to gather any more information. What I did was unplug the GPU to see if reduced power consumption solves the problem, but no change in behavior.

This is my system:

- Mainboard: GigaByte H87-HD3
- CPU: Xeon E3-1230v3
- GPU: GeForce GTX 760
- PSU: Cooler Master G550M

Answer (score 2):

From a hardware perspective, this is similar to an issue I had with an old FX series computer I built nearly 8 years ago. In my case, it was a failed cooler. Check to make sure if it is an air cooler its fins are clear of debris and the fan on top works. Additionally, after years the thermal paste on the processor is most likely dry thus inefficient. DO NOT REMOVE your cooler to check until you have new thermal paste as old and dry is better than none in most cases.

If it is liquid-cooled and uses an AIO it more than likely is the cooler.

A few things you can do is check to see if the cooler is hot, or if the backside of the MOBO where the CPU die is, is hot, if so it's most likely is a thermal problem.

PSU do go bad but it's actually quite rare in an old system with a Xeon processor the first thing I suspect is auto-power-off due to thermal limits being reached. In 15 years of building PC's thermals are one of the first things to check on a system that's more than 4 years old.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the meantime I identified the problem, but you raised a good point that I immediately checked. I would never have thought that this could happen

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. One of the RAM slots of the board is faulty.

This is a very simple thing to check in this kind of situation, I tried both RAM bars individually in the different slots and they both worked in only one of the two main slots.